# Char list instead of a string in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, argparse

I'm trying to run a command using `subprocess.check_call()`, but it appears from the output that the parameters I'm giving are not interpreted as a string but as a char list.
The command I'm trying to run: `7z x test.rar`.
What actually is running:

`subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['7z', 'x', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '.', 'r', 'a', 'r']` returned non-zero exit status 2.

For some reason, the file name is separated in the characters. What am I missing?

The code:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("input", help="File/Folder to extract")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    extract_file(args.input)

def extract_file(file):
    extract_cmd = ['7z']
    extract_cmd.extend('x')
    extract_cmd.extend(file)
    subprocess.check_call(extract_cmd)
```

Comment: `extract_cmd.extend(file)` is treating the string like an array of character values it seems. Try changing it to `extract_cmd.extend([file])` or `extract_cmd.append(file)`

Comment: @brittenb that's exactly what `list.extend()` does... The OP can just use `subprocess.check_call(['7z', 'x', file])` directly though...

Comment: It appears that using `extract_cmd.extend(['x', file])` solves the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for lists and strings covers this quite accurately.  `extend` puts new elements into a list, and you started with a list containing a single string.  You never used the string concatenation operator.  Try this, instead:

```
def extract_file(file_name):
    extract_cmd = ["7z x " + file_name]
    subprocess.check_call(extract_cmd)
```

Note: I changed your parameter, because `file` is a built-in type.

Comment: I don't know if this will work as is since the default check_call() command expects a list of args

Comment: @LeKhan9  Thanks; fixed that.  I'm trying to keep close to OP's original presentation, and went overboard.

Comment: Hm, no worries. I am not sure if that will work either though, you actually need a true list representation where this string is split up by spaces. Or you can try a pure shell approach like I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two approaches here:

```
subprocess.check_call(['7z', 'x', file])
```

or if you are not too worried about a shell injection and this is local code, just pass the entire string:

```
subprocess.check_call('{} {} {}'.format('7z', 'x', file), shell=True)
```

Others have already chimed in on why you are seeing "chars" in your list. extend will *listify* your string (file_name in this case) and add it to the end of your list.

```
a = [11]
a.extend('apples')
print a
```

output:

```
[11, 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 's']
```

Comment: but in case i just want my result to be [11,'apples'] ?

Comment: Well, for that trivial example. Just append it -  a.append('apples') :)